# How could I make a fullname search work with a seperate last and firstname?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-like

I'm new to SQL and I'm trying to make a basic query work.

This is the table and it's layout that I'm trying to search against:
[https://prnt.sc/20wj54g](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A40Xt.png)

What I'm aiming to do is have a search term input, then have the input be used to search for names in the database by fullname.

This is the current query I have now:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM personnel p
LEFT JOIN department d ON (d.id = p.departmentID)
LEFT JOIN location l ON (l.id = d.locationID)
WHERE p.firstName LIKE '%Robert Heffron%' OR p.lastName LIKE '%Robert Heffron%';
```

This doesn't work as there is no last or firstname which contains the whole string "Robert Heffron" however this means if the user typed in that string looking for that person by the full name they wouldn't find them.

I'm currently using PHP and JS to display the data but I'm struggling with the SQL part.
If anyone could help I'd be very grateful.

Comment: if you have access to the person's name in PHP. You can try splitting it with space and use a where-in clause.
WHERE p.firstName IN ('Robert','Heffron') AND p.lastName IN ('Robert','Heffron')
we are using AND instead of OR to avoid results like "John Heffron" or "Robert Williams ".

Answer (score 3):

This is not a good solution for performance, but if you want to solve the problem only using SQL, you can try this:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM personnel p
LEFT JOIN department d ON (d.id = p.departmentID)
LEFT JOIN location l ON (l.id = d.locationID)
WHERE LOWER(CONCAT(p.firstName, p.lastName)) LIKE LOWER(REPLACE('%Robert Heffron%', ' ', '%'))
OR LOWER(CONCAT(p.lastName, p.firstName)) LIKE LOWER(REPLACE('%Robert Heffron%', ' ', '%'));
```

Field concatenation is used to find a concatenated input value, and different combinations of `OR` concatenation are used to be independent of the order in which the first and last name are entered. Convert to lowercase - for case insensitive searches. We replace spaces with a `%` character to search for concatenated field values without worrying about spaces.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest adding a full name field to your database table and whenever you create a "personnel" in your code, you concatenate the first and last name:

```
Fullname = Firstname + " " + Lastname
```

if you don't like this, maybe use a string split function (in php it might be .explode()) and then adding WHERE  OR  statements for each substring for first and last name.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion but I'm unable to edit the SQL table as it is not allowed for what I've been assigned to do. A good solution otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following combination to find people whose name is *`Robert`* and whose last name is *`Heffron`*

Just find **Robert Heffron**

```
WHERE p.firstName LIKE '%Robert%' AND p.lastName LIKE '%Heffron%';
```

find all first names that have **Robert** and all last names that have **Heffron**

```
WHERE p.firstName LIKE '%Robert%' OR p.lastName LIKE '%Heffron%';
```

Comment: Sorry if it wasn't worded clearly but I'm unable to seperate as it would be a user text input which would mean both the like = '%userInput% would need to be the same'

Answer (score 0):

A solution that wouldn't ask you to change the table and having only one input variable could be something like this:

```
DECLARE @FullName AS VARCHAR(100)
SET @FullName = 'Robert Heffron'
SET @FullName = REPLACE(@FullName, ' ', '.')
SELECT....
WHERE p.firstname LIKE '%'+ ParseName(@FullName, 2) + '%' OR 
    p.firstname LIKE '%'+ ParseName(@FullName, 1) + '%' OR 
    p.lastnameLIKE '%'+ ParseName(@FullName, 2) + '%' OR 
    p.lastname LIKE '%'+ ParseName(@FullName, 1) + '%'
```

Downside in my opinion is if the user enters weird amount of spaces in the name. I have tested replacing the array number 1 or 2 in the ParseName with a number which was impossible, like 7, and it basically just ignores it.. no errors thrown or whatever. If you use this, you could test it on your side just to make sure tho.

Comment: Replace only the first 'Robert Heffron' with your input ofc

Answer (score -1):

You can use concat for the columns and can use "HAVING" clause on the concatenated column. I hope it will work for you.

```
SELECT * FROM personnel p LEFT JOIN department d ON (d.id = p.departmentID) LEFT JOIN location l ON (l.id = d.locationID) HAVING CONCAT(firstName,' ',lastName) LIKE '%Robert Heffron%';
```

I hope this snippet will work for you.

Comment: Using `HAVING` in queries without `GROUP BY` is fishy and, [according to the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html), causes degraded performance.